# Filter to display only certain columns Excel 2016

Tags: excel, filter

I have a set of data with headers in Row 1 (A to D, corresponding to Header1, Header2 etc). I would like to have a filter that reads in all the headers within Row 1 and allows me to pick which columns to display. For example, from the drop down, I will be able to select "Header1" and have it display only column A.

I understand that the new excel function FILTER would allow me to do something like this, but unfortunately for me, I am using Excel 2016 and do not have such a luxury.

Grateful for all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX/MATCH()` combination.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$5,ROW($A1),MATCH($G$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `HLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()` & `MATCH()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=HLOOKUP($G$1,$A$1:$D$10,ROW(),0)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$10,ROW()-1,MATCH($F$1,$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

---